# C# HEX a ASCII con carácter especial

Tags: c#

En este método logro hacer la conversión HEX a Ascii pero sucede que rompe cuando el HEX tiene un `/`

Por ejemplo el método lo uso para convertir `2f 50 72 75 65 62 61` que en ascii es `/Prueba`

Pero al realizar la conversión con el método no funciona porque tiene la `/` pero si le saco `/` convierte normal.

```
public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
{
    hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
    byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
    {
        raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return raw;
}
```

Comment: hay algunas respuestas aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613279/c-sharp-hex-to-ascii

Comment: @B.ClayShannon No encontré referencia a caracteres especiales. ¿Podrías indicarme?

Comment: Tal vez functioniert asi? He intentarlo (Disculpen, no se mucho español.)? Pruebe una vez: 
for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
{
    string hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
    sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16)));
}

Comment: podrias mencionar como invocas ese metodo para obtener el string resultante ? no veo como un byte[] puede devolver "/Prueba"

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, pero como Leandro tengo curiosidad, para que usas este método?

Comment: El metodo lo uso
byte[] byteConversion = DataManagment.FromHex("43-45-4e-54-49-4e-45-4c-41-20");
            string conversion = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteConversion);
            Console.WriteLine(conversion);

estoy estudiando conexiones entre Servidor - Cliente y a través de un proxy obtengo los paquetes, uno de los paquetes que envia el cliente es en Ascii "/Prueba " (sin "")

Comment: interesante, veo que tu string  contiene "-", lo agregué a la respuesta, pensé no era necesario ya que comentabas la entrada era: "2f507275656261"

Comment: de casualidad esta funcionalidad la obtuviste de este link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724862/converting-from-hex-to-string

Comment: @LeandroTuttini si esa funcion sí, pero lo uso en otro proyecto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Por que no usar las bondades de `using System.Linq;`...

Ejemplo:

```
public static byte[] FromHex(string hex) {
    return hex.Split('-')
              .Select(c => Convert.ToByte(c, 16))
              .ToArray();        
}
```

Explicación:

- `hex.Split('-')` divide hex en un array de string usando `-` como delimitador, lo que nos da un arreglo así: `["2f", "50", ... "61"]`.
- `Select(c => Convert.ToByte(c, 16))` para cada elemento del array anterior lo convierte a `byte` en base 16. Lo que retorna un `IQueryable<byte>`, por que la mágia de Select es que puede cambiar el tipo de la colección.
- `ToArray()` convierte el `IQueryable` a un `byte[]`.

Evidencias:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/eGjFq4

#### Para la operación inversa puedes usar algo así:

```
public static string ToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    return string.Join("-", 
           bytes.Select(c=> String.Format("{0:x2}", Convert.ToInt32(c))));
}
```

Explicación:

- `String.Format("{0:x2}", Convert.ToInt32(c))` convierte cada `byte` en su representacion hexadecimal. Ej. / en 2f
- `Select(c => String.Format(...))` por cada byte ejecuta la sentencia anterior lo que nos da un `IQueryable<String>` así: `["2f", "50", ... "61"]`.
- `string.Join("-", bytes.Select(...))` construye una cadena con todos los elementos del `IQueryable<String>` separados por el caracter `-`.

Evidencias: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xmgAvp

Por su puesto, puedes utilizar el delimitador que quieras.

Comment: Amo a LINQ, y cada día que pasa aún más.

Comment: @rnrneverdies  no me funciona el metodo fromhex

lo uso así 

     string packetString = "2f 63 65 6e 74 69 6e 65 6c 61 20 31 32 30 33 39";
            DataManagment.FromHex(packetString);
            Console.WriteLine(packetString);

Comment: @AlejandroMaisonnat con ese formato debes cambiar el delimitador por un espacio.. donde dice Split('-') cambialo por Split('   ') .... el espacio no se ve pero debes poner un espacio entre ' (comilla simple)

Comment: @rnrneverdies no anda, es decir me imprime los hex, en ves de pasarme a string

Comment: espera estas imprimiendo el byte[]?, recuerda que debes convertirlo como te explico elenasys, `string resultado = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(FromHex(hex));` ... si quieres puedes ponerlo dentro de la funcion y retornar directamente un string.

Comment: @AlejandroMaisonnat tu quieres que retorne directamente un string en lugar de un byte[]?, dime asi modifico la respuesta.

Comment: @rnrneverdies Muchas gracias por las prontas respeustas tambien! =) Te comento el app que tengo lo que hace es ser un proxy entre un cliente y servidor. 

Ahora los datos llegan al proxy desde el servidor binarios ,HEX.

Lo que necesitaria es 2 metodos uno para pasarlo a hex a txt y otro de txt para Hex (porque necesito parsear el paquete)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35989/discussion-between-rnrneverdies-and-alejandro-maisonnat).

Answer (score 2):

Este cambio sería suficiente:

#### Convertir string a byte-Array:

```
public static byte[] FromHex(String hex){
        hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
        int len = hex.Length;
        byte[] raw = new byte[len / 2];
        /*for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
        raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }*/
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2){
            raw[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return raw;
    }
```

En caso contrario, para convertir de `byte[]` a `string`:

#### Convertir byte-Array a string:

```
  string resultado = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(miByteArray);
```

#### Obtener el hexadecimal de un string:

```
   private static string HexFromString(String miString){
        string hexOutput = "";
        char[] values = miString.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char letter in values)
        {        
          int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);             
           hexOutput += String.Format("{0:X}", value);              
        }
        return hexOutput;
    }
```

Por ejemplo con:

```
String resultado = HexFromString("/Prueba");
```

resultado obtendría un valor de:

```
"2F507275656261"
```

Comment: por alguna razón me da error en el 

 raw[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);

será que tiene algo que ver el caractere /

Comment: No debe afectar, ¿Como estas llamando el método?  por ejemplo :     byte[] mibyte = FromHex("2f-50-72-75-65-62-61"); y si lo conviertes a string con System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mibyte); obtendrías: "/Prueba"

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys por tu tiempo y colaboración, lo pude resolver!!

Comment: una duda, en el caso que sea inverso, es decir que yo desee convertir /Prueba a HEX (con la / incluso) como sería?

Comment: string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mibyte);, lo he agregado a la respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Una consulta vos podrías mostrarme un metodo ToHex es decir de Hex a String?

Ejemplo al escribir "/Prueba " devuelva el HEX

Comment: Listo, lo agregué como : "Obtener el hexadecimal de un string"

Comment: no lo puedo usar, me da error =/

Comment: Que error te marca y usando que método y que entrada?