# Convertir un string hexadecimal a byte y viceversa

Tags: c#

Hola quiero saber como pasar de un hexadecimal que es un string a un byte.
Por ejemplo "0x0A" quiero obtener un 10. Como lo hago?

Llevo un rato intententandolo con el método Convert, conversiones implicitas, etc. Pero el usuario introduce 0x0A y no sólo 0A y no sé como hacerlo sin hacer un foreach recorriendo todo el string.

El error que me sale es que la cadena no tiene el formato correcto. Dice que es un `Date Time`.

Este es el codigo

```
ConfData.MyAdd.NodeA_Add = Byte.Parse(textBox_NodoA.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: Hola Xim. Busca en google, por ejemplo, el sistema de conversión e intenta implementarlo. Si tienes dudas o problemas concretos, pregunta aqui suguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Asi como está, la pregunta es muy amplia. Un saludo

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/4363/15301

Comment: Es dificil entenderla. Por qué no nos pones un ejemplo de lo que intentas, y que error te da? Porque "no me funciona" no da muchas pistas para poder ayudarte

Comment: El error que me sale es que la cadena no tiene el formato correcto (me dice que es un Date Time)

Comment: Xim, toda informacion relevante, como la de tu ultimo comentario, ha de ir en la pregutna, no en los comentarios. Piensa que los comentarios deberian poder borrarse y no afectar en nada a la pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] para añadir esa informacion.

Comment: Si el problema es el 0x,la solución es sencilla, reemplazar(Replace) 0x con una cadena vacía. Pero como te dije, lo mejor es que en tu pregunta pongas un ejemplo de código de lo que estas haciendo, y exactamente la excepción que te da con el. De esa manera es mucho mas facil recibir ayuda

Comment: De acuerdo voy a probarlo gracias

Comment: Ves, con el código es mas sencillo. Simplemente haz `ConfData.MyAdd.NodeA_Add = Byte.Parse(textBox_NodoA.Text.Replace("0x",""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);`

Comment: @Pikoh Vale, también podria hacer Remove no es así?

Comment: Ya me sale gracias a todos por ayudar con respuestas constructivas.

Comment: Con `Remove` debes especificar el inicio de lo que quieres quitar y el número de caracteres. En ese caso, deberías comprobar si los dos primeros caracteres son `0x`. Con `Replace`, te olvidas,si existe lo quita y si no lo deja como está

Comment: Vale gracias @Pikoh

Comment: @Mariano si, es verdad, yo soy mucho de _respuentarios_ :) Ya he añadido la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Te puede ayudar estos dos metodos (dale una mirada y modificalos para que te ayuden)

Ejemplo para **convertir de String a Hex**

```
 private static string StringToHexConvertidor(string cadenaAConvertir)
    {
        char[] valores = cadenaAConvertir.ToCharArray();
        var resultado = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char caracter in valores)
        {
            int valorInt32 = Convert.ToInt32(caracter);
            string valorHex = String.Format("{0:X}", valorInt32);
            resultado.Append(valorHex);
            resultado.Append(" ");
        }
        return resultado.ToString();
    }
```

Ejemplo para **convertir de Hex a String**

```
 private static string HexToStringConvertidor(string cadenaHex)
    {
        string[] valores = cadenaHex.Split(" ");
        var resultado = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (String hex in valores)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hex))
            {
                int valorInt16 = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
                string cadenaValor = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(valorInt16);
                resultado.Append(cadenaValor);
            }
        }
        return resultado.ToString();
    }
```

Te dejo el ejemplo completo en C# con una app de consola aqui

- HexToStringConverter.cs
  https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/4a97ec3544060c54b09d16c2750e5d40

Te puede ayudar este doc

- [How to: Convert Between Hexadecimal Strings and Numeric Types (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-between-hexadecimal-strings-and-numeric-types)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes convertir una cadena hexadecimal a byte utilizando el método `Parse` de la propia clase `Byte`:

```
Byte.Parse("0A", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

Eso sí, sin el prefijo "0x".

Para hacer la conversión inversa no tienes más que utilizar el método `ToString` con el formato "X2":

```
((Byte)10).ToString("X2")
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el método `Parse` de `Byte` espera una cadena que no comience por `0x`,y por eso da una excepción de sintaxis.

La solución mas sencilla es hacer uso del método `Replace` de `string`, que sustituye la cadena que le indiques por otra,y si no aparece la cadena a buscar simplemente devuelve la original. En este caso, buscamos `0x` y lo sustituimos por una cadena vacía:

```
ConfData.MyAdd.NodeA_Add = Byte.Parse(textBox_NodoA.Text.Replace("0x",""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```